# Pinch to zoom in Chrome with X11

Tags: 20.04, xorg, wayland, zooming

Is there any way to have pinch to zoom functionality on Chrome, Ubuntu 22.04 and X11?

The functionality works well with Wayland but using Wayland introduces bugs that I don't want.

Comment: How about the Chrome extension [mouse pinch-to-zoom](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/mouse-pinch-to-zoom/pffiadlahfhoniddbipeiiohjnlongfi?pli=1)?

Comment: Kind of nice but it won't work without an external mouse. @GAD3R